# Unable to create a "set" accessor for Dictionary

Tags: c#, set

I was originally experiencing a problem in my code in which I was unable to "add" an item to a list object.  After reviewing the list object however, I realized it only contained a "get", not a "set".  So, I'm trying to create a set accessor but I'm having issues:
Here's my original code to add an item to the list object.  Currently, nothing gets added:

```
ClientCompany clientCompany = new ClientCompany();
LocationData urlData = new LocationData();
Location location = urlData.LocationGet(1129);  //hardcoded 1129 in for now
clientCompany.Locations.Add(location);  //"location" is NOT null, however nothing gets added to Locations object

return clientCompany;   //clientCompany.Locations.Count = 0 (it should equal 1)
```

And here's the current portion of the ClientCompany class I'm having trouble with:

```
public Dictionary<int, Location> LocationsDict { get; set; }

// List Properties
public List<Location> Locations
{
    get { return LocationsDict.Values.ToList(); }
}
```

I tried including a setter, but I receive the following error:

> Cannot convert source type
>   `Systems.Collections.Generic.List<MyCompany.MVC.MyProject.Models.ClientCompany.Location>'
>   to target type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,
>   MyCompany.MVC.MyProject.Models.ClientCompany.Location>`

```
 get { return LocationsDict.Values.ToList(); }
 set { LocationsDict = value; }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you assign a list of locations to a dictionary of ints paired with locations?  The compiler doesn't know what to do, hence the error.

Comment: hi @goalie35 can you add ClientCompany and LocationData ,Location code and what the key in your LocationDict suppose to be ,we need to understand your logic and what you wanna do with it ? thx

Comment: i think that your key need to be contained in Location or calculated throught properties in location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i 'll do something like this:

```
private Dictionary<int, Location> LocationsDict = new Dictionary<int, Location>();

public void Set(int key, Location value)
{
    if (LocationsDict.ContainsKey(key))
        LocationsDict[key] = value;
    else
        LocationsDict.Add(key, value);
}

public Location Get(int key)
{
    return LocationsDict.ContainsKey(key) ? LocationsDict[key] : null; }
}
```

or better (i think) you could use indexer:

```
public class MyClass
{   
    private readonly IDictionary<int, Location> LocationsDict = new Dictionary<int, Location>();
    public Location this[int key]
    {
        get { return LocationsDict.ContainsKey(key) ? LocationsDict[key] : null; }

        set 
        {     
            if (LocationsDict.ContainsKey(key))
                LocationsDict[key] = value;
            else
                LocationsDict.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}

var gotest = new MyClass();
gotest[0] = new Location(){....};
```